# Passing a variable that can be updated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers

This seems like a simple thing, but can't get it to work.

I pass a variable into a UIViewController thourgh a standard property:

```
[aViewController setProposedDate:proposedWorkLog.entryDate];
```

which is retained by the controller, and possible changed. I have verified that in the controller, the data is modified.

But, after it is popped off the stack and I look in the calling view, the data has not been updated.  Is there a way to pass this variable and have it retain the new value, or a way to pass back a response from a closing view controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a pointer to the variable? Or does Objective-C have a way you can pass a variable by reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to modify a property (`entryDate`) behind the owner's (`proposedWorkLog`) back, this may come with many side effects like inconsistency and memory mismanagement.

I *strongly* suggest to go a different route, maybe pass the `proposedWorkLog` and call setters for the new property on it.

`entryDate` *looks* like a NSDate which is immutable, so you can't change it; you have to replace it with a new instance which is best done by invoking the correct setter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it by reference. Objects in Objective-C are passed by reference because they (usually) are pointers, but primitives on the other hand, are (usually) not pointers. So you need to pass in a pointer to the primitive by using the address-of operator (`&`).

So your code should look like this:

`[aViewController setProposedDate:&proposedWorkLog.entryDate];`

You then need to change your method prototype to take a pointer to the primitive type (say `int *`).

Have a look at the way error handling with `NSError` works in Objective-C, it's using this methodology all over the place. http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/04/cocoa-tutorial-using-nserror-to-great-effect/

Comment: Technically correct, but passing a pointer to a property (most likely primitive or immutable) opens the door to all kind of inconsistencies and memory problems. Basically the code says: Change my property behind my back.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with @Eiko.  You should think about it a bit differently.  In C++ you can do stuff like `void flipTheseTwo(int* x, int* y)` but I'm pretty sure that is bad form for Objective-C (and retain'd memory objects).

Here's my suggestion.  Use `@property (assign) MYWorklog worklog;` `@synthesize worklog = _worklog;`

```
[aViewController setWorklog:proposedWorkLog];
[UINavicationController pushViewController: aViewController animated:YES]; // this syntax might be wrong.  Mac is not near me. :(

...

(IBAction) updateProposedDate:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
    _worklog.entryDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[sender stringValue]];  
    [dateFormat release];

}
```